# Multiple setIntervals with one function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

This code randomly plays Audio elements. Running `setup` twice allows you to do this with two different arrays simultaneously, which is what I want. The problem is that `#stop` only stops one of the arrays playing. This actually also happens if you only call `setup` on one array, but click `#start` more than once (which I also don't want). I figure this has to do with 'intervalReturn', as it would only be specified to one `setInterval`.

How should I write this so that multiple invocations of `setup` creates distinct setIntervals which can be started only once?

Alternately, if I should approach this from a totally different angle, what would be better?

EDIT: This was fixed per the suggestions below. But I'm wondering, what is going on "under the hood" with setInterval here? Why does this behavior happen at all? (Specifically: `#stop` stops one but not all audio elements.)

```
var CMajor3 = new Array ("C3","D3","E3","F3","G3","A3","B3","C4a");
var CMajor4 = new Array ("C4b","D4","E4","F4","G4","A4","B4","C5");

var intervalReturn = null;  

function pickAndPlay(pitchSet){
    fyshuffle (pitchSet);  // the Fischer-Yates shuffle function
    var tone = document.getElementById(pitchSet[0]);
    tone.currentTime = 0;
    tone.play();    
};

function setup(time, pitchSet){
    $("#start").click(function() {   
        console.log("startClicked"); 
        intervalReturn = window.setInterval(pickAndPlay, time, pitchSet)
    }); 
    $("#stop").click(function() {   
        console.log("stopClicked");  
        window.clearInterval(intervalReturn)
    }); 
};  

$(document).ready(function() {  
    setup(2000, CMajor3);
    setup(2000, CMajor4);
});
```

Comment: the problem is the single `intervalReturn` variable can't hold two different values simultaneously! - try moving `var intervalReturn = null` to be the first line in `function setup`

Comment: see the edit to the comment?

Comment: *"This...also happens if you...click #start more than once."* - Is that something that you want to be able to do? Or should the user have to stop the previous one before clicking start again?

Comment: @Jaromanda Yes - thanks. Moving `intervalReturn` into `setup` does stop both arrays when they are playing simultaneously. However you can still `#start` multiple playbacks, only one of which can be `#stop`ed. Perhaps I could prevent this with something to the effect of if(intervalReturn !== null)...?

Comment: You could do `if (intervalReturn !== null)` as long as you explicitly set it back to `null` in the `#stop` function.

Comment: @nnnnnn alas, that doesn't work. At least with `if... intervalReturn` in the `#start` function... it prevents it from calling at all since it's null to begin with.

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, you'd want the opposite, `if (intervalReturn === null)` then call `setInterval()` in the `#start` function, and reset it to `null` in the `#stop`. In other words, "if not already running then start..."

Comment: @nnnnnn yes! of course. that does it. thanks!

Comment: See the edit above if you have the chance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **But I'm wondering, what is going on "under the hood" with setInterval here?**

Each time you call `setup()`, that creates *additional* click handlers on the `#start` and `#stop` elements. When you actually click `#start`, or `#stop`, *all* of the applicable handlers are called (in the same order they were bound). This is why clicking `#start` causes both `CMajor3` *and* `CMajor4` notes to play. You get multiple concurrent but unrelated intervals running.

With `intervalReturn` defined as a global variable, you only ever have the interval ID that was returned from the most recent call to `setInterval()`, because each time the `#start` click handler runs it overwrites the previous one. That's why clicking `#stop` only ever stops one of the intervals and there is no way to stop the others.

Moving the `var intervalReturn` declaration inside the `setup()` function helps because the way [closures work in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) is that the arguments and local variables of `setup()`, i.e., `time`, `pitchSet` and `intervalReturn` (after you've moved the declaration) are accessible in the two event handlers defined in the *current* call to `setup()`. Subsequent calls to `setup()` create new closures with their own separate copies of those variables. So then the `#stop` click handler uses the individual `intervalReturn` relevant to its own `setup()`. And since both `#stop` handlers run, both intervals get cleared.

But you still have the problem that clicking `#start#` more than once without clicking `#stop` creates additional intervals and then within any one `setup()` that individual `intervalReturn` gets overwritten with the latest, so again `#stop` has no way to refer back to the previous intervals. Which is why adding `if (intervalReturn === null)` in the `#start` handler helps to only start a new interval if there is not already one running. (And then you need to add `intervalReturn = null` in the `#stop` handler because just calling `clearInterval(intervalReturn)` doesn't change the value of the `intervalReturn` variable.)

**Suggestion:** Update your existing `console.log()` statements to the following:

```
console.log("startClicked", pitchSet, intervalReturn); 
// and
console.log("stopClicked", pitchSet, intervalReturn);
```

And maybe more the `startClicked` one to just after calling `setInterval()` so that it logs the interval ID that was just returned, not the *previous* one. That way you can see the values of all of the relevant variables and see what is happening.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you greatly for this thorough explanation. It makes it much more clear what I need to study up on to understand this project.